# How to use list comprehension in dict comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary

How would the following nested list comprehension be used in below dict comprehension to extract keys for the dict?

```
key = [key for element in cont.select('span.number') for key in element['class']] #extracts keys

data = dict((k, v.get_text(strip=True)) for k, v in zip(cont.select('span.number, h4.name, span.position'), cont.select('span.number, h4.name, span.position'))) #creates a dict with three keys and three values
```

The goal is to extract the class name of a specific tag as a key and it's text as a value.

```
Working example below:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
from lxml import html
from pprint import pprint
player_page = requests.get('https://www.premierleague.com/clubs/43/Burnley/squad')
cont = soup(player_page.content, 'lxml')
key_number = [key for element in cont.select('span.number') for key in element['class']]
key_name = [key for element in cont.select('h4.name') for key in element['class']]
key_position = [key for element in cont.select('span.position') for key in element['class']]

data = {
        k: v.get_text(strip=True)
        for k,v in zip((number,name,position), cont.select('span.number', 'h4.name', 'span.position')) for (number,name,position) in zip(key_number,key_name,key_position)  
    }
```

Expected output:

```
{'Burnley': {'number': 'some_number',
            'name': 'some_name',
            'position': 'some_postion'},
            {'number': 'some_number',
            'name': 'some_name',
            'position': 'some_postion'}
}
```

EDIT: I have figured some things out but can't understand why I get error message `name 'number' is not defined` ?

Comment: You're trying to get the dictionary `{{'number:NUMBER'},{'name':NAME},{'position':POSITION}}`, a dictionary with no keys?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, edited the post to make it more clear. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Can you include what `key` and `cont.select('span.number, h4.name, span.position')` contain?